# Count elements from ForeignKey with condition

Tags: django, django-models

I have a view, which returns all Company objects. In my HTML file I want to count all Ads which are online (`online == True`) and belong to the Company.
In my file *companySearch.html* all Ads are counted, even those which have `online == False`.

I am looking for a way which should have the logic of:

```
{{ o.ad_set.count where o.ad.online == True }}
```

*views.py*

```
def companySearch(request):
    obj = Company.objects.all()
    
    paginator = Paginator(obj, PAGINATION_NUMBER)
    page_number = request.POST.get('page')
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)

    context = {'obj': page_obj}
    return render(request, 'core/companySearch.html', context)
```

*models.py*

```
class Company(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=False, null=False, unique=True)    


class Ad(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=False, null=False)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    online = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

*companySearch.html*

```
{% for o in obj %}
    <div>{{ o.ad_set.count }} open position{{ o.ad_set.count|pluralize:',s' }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

`ad_set` is actually a Model Manager, acted as normal `model.objects` query set, so you can simply filter the related instance with following code:

```py
o.ad_set.filter(online=True).count()
```

Another way to get the ad is_online=True number is utilize annotate function:
(This is more recommended then the above answer because of the N+1 query issue)

```py
from django.db.models import Count, Q


obj = Company.objects.annotate(online_ad_count=Count('ad_set', filter=Q(ad_set__online=True)).all()

o.online_ad_count # get count number with customized annotate field
```

See [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet) for more detailed info.

---

You can also use [Prefetch](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) to help you with these problem, but I think annotate is qualified enough.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I get following error:
"Could not parse the remainder: '(is_online=True).count()' from 'o.ad_set.filter(is_online=True).count()"
I also tried your second approach. It seems to be that it filters the element with the wrong model. It lists all entries from the Company model instead of the Ad model

Comment: Well, maybe precisely define the `related_name` in the Foreign key fields may help?

```python
company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="advertisings")

c = company.object.get(id=1)
c.advertisings.count()   #  call like this with related_name
```

Comment: Sorry @GCMeccariello I saw where the problem is, i mistook your ad field to `is_online`, it should be `online`, i have revised my answer, give it a try!

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried that aswell. But it does not work in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I found another approach which works well for me. I wrote my own custom template filter which simply counts all "True" values and returns it.

*companySearch.html*

```
{% for o in obj %}
    {{ o.ad_set.all|countOnline:o.ad_set.all }}
{% endfor %}
```

*my_templates.py*

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()


def countOnline(value, arg):
    online_nr = 0
    for v in value:

        if v.online == True:
            online_nr = online_nr + 1
        else:
            pass

    return online_nr

register.filter('countOnline', countOnline)
```